# Exclude multiple lines of object using -notcontains operator?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, office365api

I wanted to filter out or exclude the two or more licenses assigned to the user by using the below simple query, but it is not doing anything.

The line below still includes the two licenses described in the $Skip variable:

```
#License to ignore
$Skip = 'M365_E5', 'FLOW_FREE'  

$SKU = @(Get-MgUserLicenseDetail -UserId 'Username@domain.com') | 
            Where-Object { $_.SkuPartNumber -notcontains $Skip }
```

Appendix: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mguserlicensedetail?view=graph-powershell-1.0#-filter

Comment: In short: [`-contains` / `-notcontains`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) are _collection operators_: they test if the LHS object is _equal in full_ to at least one element of the RHS collection. They are not to be confused with the  `.Contains()` .NET _method_ for _substring matching_.  While PowerShell has no equivalent operator for _literal_ substring matching, you can use `-like` with _wildcard expressions_ or `-match` with _regular expressions_, both of which are case-_insensitive_.

Comment: The right side of -contains gets converted into a string so `'M365_E5 FLOW_FREE'` And this is true `'M365_E5 FLOW_FREE' -contains 'M365_E5','FLOW_FREE'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-[not]contains` operator(s) is for collection containment - whereas you want to perform one or more *substring searches*, preferably using the `-like` or `-match` operators.

To if *any* of a given number of terms is found as a substring in a given input string, use the `.Where()` extension method in `First`-mode:

```
... |Where-Object { $SkuPartNumber = $_.SkuPartNumber; @($Skip).Where({$SkuPartNumber -like "*$_*"}, 'First').Count -eq 0 }
```

If *any* of the strings in `$Skip` is found in the part number, the `Count` of the resulting value will be greater than 0 and the object won't filter through.

---

As an alternative approach, you could also construct a regex pattern matching either term and use that with the `-notmatch` regex operator:

```
# generate a valid regex pattern in the form (?:term1|term2|...|termN)
$SkipPattern = '(?:{0})' -f $($Skip.ForEach({[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|')
```

Then:

```
... |Where-Object { $_.SkuPartNumber -notmatch $SkipPattern}
```

Comment: yes, this is so cool, I've learn something new here, that you can add more lines inside the Where-Object clause :-)
Thank you for your help.